# Using inversify-express-utils, how can i integrate websockets?

Tags: node.js, express, typescript, socket.io, inversifyjs

We try to connect to extend our *typescript* application based on *inversify-express-utils* with *websockets*, but no luck so far:

```
import 'reflect-metadata';
import {interfaces, InversifyExpressServer, TYPE} from 'inversify-express-utils';
import { Kernel } from 'inversify';
import {UserController} from './controller/UserController';
import TYPES from './constant/types';
import * as socketIo from 'socket.io';

// set up kernel
let kernel = new Kernel();

// create server
let server = new InversifyExpressServer(kernel);
kernel.bind<interfaces.Controller>(TYPE.Controller).to(UserController).whenTargetNamed(TAGS.UserController);
server
  .build()
  .listen(3000, 'localhost', () => console.log('listening on http://localhost:3000'));

// try to setup a socket io based websocket
let io = socketIo(server);
io.on('connect', (socket) => console.log('"connect" executed'));
io.on('connection', (socket) => console.log('"connection" executed'));
```

Server starts up as expected with `ts-node server.ts`.
But I can't connect to this web socket. Tried it with several tools, like for example Dark WebSocket Terminal chrome plugin and executing `\connect localhost:3000`. 
Any idea?

Comment: Hi, I have reported this issue to the InversifyJS team and we are investigating it at https://github.com/inversify/InversifyJS/issues/413 we have never used web sockets with the express utils before so maybe this is a missing feature but I will keep you updated.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'll follow [InversifyJS/issues/413](http://github.com/inversify/InversifyJS/issues/413)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've got some similar issue some time ago. Here is what was worked for me:

```
let server: interfaces.InversifyExpressServer = new InversifyExpressServer(kernel);

server.setConfig((app) => {
    ... 
    app.use(helmet());
    ...
});

let app = server.build();

let instance: any = app.listen(config.url.port);
console.log(`Server started on port ${config.url.port} :)`);


let socketIO = SocketIO.listen(instance);
socketIO.on('connection', (socket: SocketIO.Server) => {
    socket.emit('news', { hello: 'world' });
    socket.on('my other event', function (data: any) {
        console.log(data);
    });
});

exports = module.exports = app;
```

As you can see, you have to create a running instance of your express server before you can attach Socket.IO on to it. Your `server` variable is not enough. I hope this will work for you.

Best regards
.... Simon

Answer (score 2):

A working example can be found on https://github.com/dkellenb/inversify-express-utils-websockets The issue was:

- Server wrapper needs to be created around the app
- Listen should be started on the on the express server
- Test connection string should look like this:
  `ws://localhost:3000/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket`

Code snippet:

```
// server.build() actually returns an Express.Application instance
let app = server.build();

// socket.io expects an http.Server versus a InversifyExpressServer
// see http://socket.io/docs/#using-with-express-3/4
let httpServer = require('http').createServer(app);
httpServer.listen(3000);

// create socket.io
let io = socketIo(httpServer);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import * as express from 'express';
import * as expressWs from 'express-ws';
import { InversifyExpressServer } from 'inversify-express-utils';
import { container } from "./utils/InversifyConfig";

let inversifyExpressServer = new InversifyExpressServer(container);
  inversifyExpressServer.setConfig((app: expressWs.Application) => {
     expressWs(app);
     // Your other config
  });
```